# Is "Crypto Key" and "privateKey" the same in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the whole video she used a "privateKey":
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODeXo7YIwVg&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

While she mentioned "Crypto Key", the "Crypto Key" is never used though.

I wonder whether it is just a minor mistake, i.e. she meant "Crypto Key" when she talked about "privateKey", or whether there is a "privateKey". If this is the case, where do I get the "privateKey"?

Also @8:59 she said "no low standard characters". Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, but what does "no low standard characters" mean? It can't be lower case characters, because in her example there were lower case characters too. Google didn't help either in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Both are the same.